# Woocommerce Order received E-mail

Tags: woocommerce, email-templates

We did changes to the WooCommerce checkout to prevent showing any prices, and we added custom fields to the checkout, and we hide the additional information field. It works all the only problem in the order confirmation e-mail to the customer the table with the products and is showing a row underneath the products with this Symbol: `?>`.

I can not find where this is coming from, probably there would usually the "additional information" being displayed?

[screenshot of the order-received e-mail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TsW48.jpg)

Any idea which WooCommerce templates I would need to change?

I tried to modify the order-details.php and the `order-item-details.php` but without any success.

Comment: Acoording to provided details, it seems that there is additional closing PHP tag "?>" in woocommerce email template file "email-order-details.php", "email-order-items.php", which is getting displayed in email details.

Comment: Thanks Jai, found it there
thanks to your help :)

Comment: any idea how we will get rid of the empty column next to Quantity where usuall the price is displayed?

Comment: To hide "price" column in woocommerce order email, in file "email-order-details.php", "email-order-items.php", the code containing "td" tag, in which price is displayed, should be removed or commented.